# Expression type '' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, tuples

Here's my test script snippet. I'm getting a compile error on the line where trying to assign a tuple to a constant.

```
class Test: UIView {
    struct Properties {
        var properties:  (coordinatesXY: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, group: String, fillingColor: UIColor)

    }

    var circleCollection: [Properties] = []

    private func getProperties() -> [Properties] {
        return circleCollection

    }

    private func getShape(circleProperties properties: Properties) {
        let (coordinatesXY, radius, group, fillingColor) = properties
        //Error: Expression type 'Test.Properties' is ambiguous without more context
    }

    private func drawTheme(circleProperties properties: Properties) {
        getShape(circleProperties: properties)

    }

    private func drawMainTheme () {
        let properties = getProperties()

        for record in 0...properties.count {

            drawTheme(circleProperties: properties[record])

        }
    }

}
```

Would appreciate any help here, many thanks in advance!

Comment: You meant `properties.properties`. But why have a struct with a single tuple property? Why not make the elements of the tuple *actual* properties of the struct?

Comment: Also consider using `for property in properties` instead of indexing.

Comment: @Hamish, thank you a lot, this is what I needed.